# What can I do to improve sklearn's Jaccard similarity score performance on 9000+ data

Tags: python, performance, numpy, similarity

I am trying create a table of Jaccard similarity score on a list of vectors `x` with every other elements in the list that has over 9000 rows (so resulting to a roughly 9000, 9000 list):

```
[[  2   2  67   2   5   3  62  68  27]
[  2   9  67   2   1   3  20  62 139]
[  2  17  67   2   0   6   6  62  73]
[  2  17  67   2   0   6  39  68  92]
[  0   0  67   0   0   3  62  62  13]
...
```

I'm a beginner so I tried to my implement shameful excuse of a code like this:

```
similarities_matrix = np.empty([len(x), len(x)])
for icounter, i in enumerate(x.as_matrix()):
    similarities_row = np.empty(len(x))
    for jcounter, j in enumerate(x.as_matrix()):
        similarities_row[jcounter] = jaccard_similarity_score(i, j)
    similarities_matrix[icounter] = similarities_row
pprint(similarities_matrix)
```

But it runs impossibly slow.

Ideally I wanted my code to run within the span of my lifetime (preferably under 5 minutes.)

Currently, this code runs roughly a second per element to compute the similarity matrix.

Comment: If the slow part is the line `jaccard_similarity_score(i, j)` then we can't really help you without knowing what the function is looking up.

Comment: OH, dang i forgot to state that `jaccard_similarity_score()` is from `sklearn.metrics` sorry about that.

Comment: Also not sure how slow x.as_matrix() runs, but you may want to do it once first and put the result in a variable rather than do it once in each enumerate.

Also printing is really slow, check how fast it runs without the pprint.

Comment: I think there's only so much you can do here.  You're doing 9000**4 calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind using `scipy`, you can use the function [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) from `scipy.spatial.distance`.  The value computed by `sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score(u, v)` is equivalent to `1 -`[`scipy.spatial.distance.hamming(u, v)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.hamming.html). For example,

```
In [71]: from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score

In [72]: from scipy.spatial.distance import hamming

In [73]: u = [2, 1, 3, 5]

In [74]: v = [2, 1, 4, 5]

In [75]: jaccard_similarity_score(u, v)
Out[75]: 0.75

In [76]: 1 - hamming(u, v)
Out[76]: 0.75
```

`'hamming'` is one of the metrics provided by [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html), so you can use that function to compute all the pairwise distances.  Here's a small `x` to use as an example:

```
In [77]: x = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(8, 10))

In [78]: x
Out[78]: 
array([[4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0],
       [3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 4],
       [3, 0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4],
       [3, 0, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3]])
```

I'll use [`squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) to convert the output of `pdist` to the symmetric array of similarities.

```
In [79]: from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

In [80]: squareform(1 - pdist(x, metric='hamming'))
Out[80]: 
array([[ 1. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.1,  0.3,  0.4,  0. ],
       [ 0.1,  1. ,  0.3,  0. ,  0.3,  0.1,  0.2,  0.4],
       [ 0.2,  0.3,  1. ,  0.1,  0.3,  0.2,  0.3,  0.2],
       [ 0.3,  0. ,  0.1,  1. ,  0.1,  0.3,  0.4,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0.3,  0.3,  0.1,  1. ,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.3,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.1,  1. ,  0.1,  0.3],
       [ 0.4,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.1,  0.1,  1. ,  0.2],
       [ 0. ,  0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.1,  0.3,  0.2,  1. ]])
```

I converted your code to this function:

```
def jaccard_sim_matrix(x):
    similarities_matrix = np.empty([len(x), len(x)])
    for icounter, i in enumerate(x):
        similarities_row = np.empty(len(x))
        for jcounter, j in enumerate(x):
            similarities_row[jcounter] = jaccard_similarity_score(i, j)
        similarities_matrix[icounter] = similarities_row
    return similarities_matrix
```

so we can verify that the `pdist` result is the same as your calculation.

```
In [81]: jaccard_sim_matrix(x)
Out[81]: 
array([[ 1. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.1,  0.3,  0.4,  0. ],
       [ 0.1,  1. ,  0.3,  0. ,  0.3,  0.1,  0.2,  0.4],
       [ 0.2,  0.3,  1. ,  0.1,  0.3,  0.2,  0.3,  0.2],
       [ 0.3,  0. ,  0.1,  1. ,  0.1,  0.3,  0.4,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0.3,  0.3,  0.1,  1. ,  0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
       [ 0.3,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.1,  1. ,  0.1,  0.3],
       [ 0.4,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.1,  0.1,  1. ,  0.2],
       [ 0. ,  0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.1,  0.3,  0.2,  1. ]])
```

Here I'll compare the timing for a larger array:

```
In [82]: x = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(500, 10))

In [83]: %timeit jaccard_sim_matrix(x)
14.9 s ± 192 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [84]: %timeit squareform(1 - pdist(x, metric='hamming'))
1.19 ms ± 2.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Finally, let's time the calculation for an input with shape (9000, 10):

```
In [94]: x = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(9000, 10))

In [95]: %timeit squareform(1 - pdist(x, metric='hamming'))
1.34 s ± 9.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

That's just 1.34 seconds--definitely within the span of a lifetime.

Comment: My god.. not only did you reduce my 1 hour of coding to one line, but also, your solution is astronomically faster! Thank you Warren!!!